# How to manage the Notification to be cancel on MainActivity of the Application?

Tags: android, android-layout, notifications, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I have Many Notification in My Application. By each Notification i am calling myProject's Main Activity.

Now there are Multiple Notification in My Application as like aNotification, BNotification. . .

I know how to cancel that notification.

i.e:

```
 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 notificationManager.cancel(NotificationConstants.NOTIFICATION_ID_EVERY_MONTH);
```

But if there are multiple Notification then how to handle it ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only way to manage multiple Notifications is to store their ids while notifying them

i.e,

```
notificatonManager.notify(int id, Notification notification)
```

Now you need to store the "int id" everytime you call this function as its unique within your app. Then later you can use it to cancel it whenever you want. Make sure to keep it unique so that you can manage every notificaion properly ....